# I want to make a website that triggers css animations on scroll, no vertical or horizontal movement. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen multiple website that have unique scrolling features, but one that stood out to me was this website that only triggered animations on scrolling, is there a way that I could do this?

I have looked up a few ways to make unique scrolling effects, but none provide me with what I need.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <a class="elementA">A</a>
        <a id="elementN">n</a>
        <a id="elementD">d</a>
        <a id="elementR">r</a>
        <a id="elementE">e</a>
        <a class="elementW">w</a>
        <a class="elementP">P</a>
        <a class="elementAA">a</a>
        <a class="elementNdrew">n</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I just want to make a website that will trigger some CSS animations whenever I scroll, without any movement. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried so far? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check [W3Schools onscroll Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) and try their examples. Should get you up and running...

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use the wheel envent and check if `e.deltaY > 0`

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling down');
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "<p><strong>hello world</strong></p>";
    
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```